# Default launch image is shown when leaving app and going back via URL schemes

Tags: ios, url-scheme, launchimage

When I trigger a Facebook share in my app (URL scheme that switches to the Facebook app, and then back again when it's done through another URL scheme associated with my app), I always see the default launch image for a second before I get the UI back.

If I leave the app by pressing the home button and going back I don't get the default launch image. Nor do I get it if I leave the app, open another app and then go back.

Tested on an iPhone 5 with iOS 8. Is this a bug in iOS 8 perhaps? Anybody else encounter this?

EDIT: Oh, and no `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` in the plist, and the app is compiled against iOS 7.

Comment: Can you check whether the app is terminated when the Facebook app is launched? Since your app might be using a lot of memory and so does Facebook your app might be killed.

Comment: It's not. Just double-checked to be sure.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? @ChristianA.Strømmen